# How to access a webpart data inside another webpart

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm building a custom web part in SharePoint 2007 using C#. I need to access  data from another custom web part.
Is it possible to access the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Connecting Custom Web Parts in SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/ConnectingCustomWebParts.aspx)

There's a lot of unimportant code in the article (creating tables, rows, cells, etc).

Focus on the methods with the `ConnectionProvider` and `ConnectionConsumer` attributes as well as the custom `ICommunicationInterface` interface.